# Detect focus in a list of TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of object `List<Item>` and each Item has a `FocusNode`, a `TextEditingController` and an `id`, number of Item is not fixed:

```
class Item {
   String id;
   TextEditingController textController;
   FocusNode focusNode;
}
```

I display each Item as a `TextField` in a `ListView` using `items[0].textController` and `items[0].focusNode` for the first `TextField` and so on. How can I detect which `TextField`  has focus? For example, if user tab on the second Textfield which is editing `items[1]` and the keyboard show up, it would trigger a function that has a line like `print(items[1].id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to the `FocusNodes`, like this:

```
items[1].focusNode.addListener(() {
  print(items[1].id);
});
```

Make sure to do this inside `initState()`